# Called two functions on route watch change in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

As I am new in Vuejs, It will be very easy for others, but for me I cannot get it right, I search a lot but cannot get the expected answer

Below is my code

```
watch: {
 $route () {
  this.newsData = []
  this.loadNewsByCategory()

  this.category = {}
  this.getCategoryData()
 }
},

created () {
 this.getCategoryData()
 this.loadNewsByCategory()
},

methods () {
 async getCategoryData() {
  // console.log('called category data')
  try {
    await firebase.firestore().collection('categories').doc(this.$route.params.id).get().then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        this.category = doc.data()
      }
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error) // this line show the error I've post below
    this.$q.notify({ type: 'negative', message: error.toString() })
  }
 },

 async loadNewsByCategory() {
  // console.log('load news')
  try {
    var db = firebase.firestore()
    var first = db.collection('posts')
      .where('publishedAt', '<=', new Date())
      .where('categories', 'array-contains', this.$route.params.id)
      .orderBy('publishedAt', 'desc')
      .limit(12)

    return await first.get().then((documentSnapshots) => {
      documentSnapshots.forEach((doc) => {
        const news = {
          id: doc.id,
          slug: doc.data().slug,
          title: doc.data().title,
          image: doc.data().image.originalUrl,
          publishedAt: dateFormat(doc.data().publishedAt.toDate(), 'dS mmm, yyyy')
        }
        this.newsData.push(news)
      })

      this.lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1]
    })
  } catch (error) {
    this.$q.notify({ type: 'negative', message: error.toString() })
  }
 }
}
```

In my code, when initialize I call two functions to query data from firebase and it's working as expected. but when the route change for example: from `getdata/1` to `getdata/2` one function i.e., `loadNewsByCategory()` is working but others throw error like below

```
TypeError: u.indexOf is not a function
 at VueComponent.getCategoryData (getdata.vue?3b03:102)
 at VueComponent.created (getdata.vue?3b03:92)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: There's not enough context to reproduce the problem (for instance, there's no code containing `indexOf` in your question). Can you link to a reproduction in Codesandbox?

Comment: @tony19 I've updated my question, please check

Comment: So I guess `firebase` is using `indexOf` under the hood. Not sure if this is a copy-paste typo, but `getCategoryData()` is async but not awaited in `created()`, so `loadNewsByCategory()` could be invoked before `getCategoryData()` resolves.

Comment: both method is async, c/p typo

Comment: I still don't see you `await`ing the call to `getCategoryData()`...

Comment: inside `try` await is there? is this what you mean?

Comment: No, in `created()`: `await this.getCategoryData()`

Comment: okay, i didn't put `await` in `created()` before.. let me try

Comment: Not working tho..

Comment: I got working like this `.doc(this.$route.params.id.toString())` in `getCategoryData()`